# Can't start Postgres 9.6 on CentOS 6

Tags: postgresql, centos6

I'm attempting to start Postgres on CentOS 6 and keep getting the following error:

```
FATAL:  could not open lock file "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock": Permission denied
```

But there's no .s.PGSQL.5432.lock file in the /var/run/postgresql directory. 
I'm running as root and have tried to reboot the server in case there was another postgres instance running and that still didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Have you tried creating /var/run/postgresql or checking the perms of that folder?

Comment: Have you tried to start with the postgres user? Root haven't permission